# Printing a degree symbol ("º") yields "unknown symbol" (question mark in romb) via Python

Tags: qgis, python-3

I am working with QGIS 2.14.3, I just create a JSON file for detecting text, numbers, bearing and distance with OCR process using python 3 with pytorch, successfully I completed for creating a JSON file. When I load my JSON file
the degree symbol is not displaying instead, it produces like in below snap:

[image]

Even I used `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in my code still getting same error

Comment: Try forcing coding to `system`, or even better, upgrade to the latest LTR.

Comment: @Erik ok, thank you!